# Parsley.js Password Confirm doesn‘t work

Tags: passwords, confirm, parsley.js

I have problem with the Parsley.js Framework.

My Problem is that the password and password confirm have the same input, but I have a error message if click on the submit button.

Here my Testsite:

http://topkosmetikstudios.de/release/index.php?article_id=21

(german language passwort = password  and password wiederholen = password confirm)

Here my Code:

```html
<div class="half right">
    <p>
        <label for="category" class="dropdown_label">Passwort</label>
        <input type="password" data-equalto="#eqalToModel" name="passwort" data-required="true" <?php echo ($_POST['passwort'])? $_POST['passwort']:""; ?>>
    </p>

</div>
<div class="half left">
    <p>
        <label for="category" class="dropdown_label">Passwort wiederholen</label>
        <input type="password" data-equalto="#eqalToModel" name="passwort_w" data-required="true">
    </p>
</div>
```

I use the Parsley.js parameter `data-equalto="#elem"` but it doesn't work.

Here the Parsley.js documentation: http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html

Does anyone see a problem with my code that would cause this to not function?

Comment: Ohh i find my bug. This Question is closed yet.

Comment: Damn what was your bug? I'm seeing the same problem!

Comment: I guess the bug is that #eqalToModel refers to an element id and he doesn't have it on the HTML tags!

Comment: If you fixed your problem, add your solution as an Answer below and then mark it "accepted".

Answer (score 20):

It's possible you're using the wrong tag, as of Parsely.js 2.0:

```
data-parsley-equalto="#anotherfield"
```

Comment: Straight Solution

Comment: This is not working if the confirm password is empty it skips the validation.

Answer (score 4):

If what you are attempting to do is make sure both **password 1** and **password 2** are the same before you submit the form then according to the documentation (http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#psly-validators-list) you need to set an **id** for the fields that you want to match against. And set **field one** to look for the **id** of **field two** and vice versa.

> Equalto #2.0  data-parsley-equalto="#anotherfield"    Validates that the
>   value is identical to another field's value (useful for password
>   confirmation check).

See the example code below:

```
<div class="half right">
    <p>
       <label for="category" class="dropdown_label">Passwort</label>
       <input id="passwort" type="password" data-equalto="#passwort_w" name="passwort" data-required="true">
    </p>

</div>
<div class="half left">
    <p>
        <label for="category" class="dropdown_label">Passwort wiederholen</label>
            <input id="passwort_w" type="password" data-equalto="#passwort" name="passwort_w" data-required="true">
     </p>
</div>
```

For more on **Parsley.js** lookup their [documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#psly-validators-list). 
Please mark this as an answer if this is what you were looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an id for the first password input (i.e. "password"), then set the *data-equalto* attribute of the second input to the same value (i.e. "#password") and it should work fine. If it does not work you might wish to check if parsley.js is loaded correctly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="half right">
    <p>
       <label for="category" class="dropdown_label">Passwort</label>
       <input id="passwort" type="password" name="passwort" data-required="true" id="passwort">
    </p>

</div> <div class="half left">
    <p>
        <label for="category" class="dropdown_label">Passwort wiederholen</label>
            <input id="passwort_w" type="password" data-equalto="#passwort" name="passwort_w" data-required="true">
     </p> </div>
```

> data-equalto="#id_of_compare_field"

Comment: I suggest you to improve your example by reading the [Minimal, Complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I suggest you to improve your "look your bussiness" ;)